# On the right inverse of a Borel measurable map between two Souslin spaces being Souslin measurable, i.e. mapping open sets back to analytic sets

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-measures

I'm currently reading some stuff on the existence of a measurable inverse, or measurable choice theorems from [Bogachev's Measure Theory book, Volume II](https://diendantoanhoc.org/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=12513), where I'm trying to connect these two theorems on measurable choice:

The first one is (see P.34): see below, the third screenshot for the definition of Souslin sets, that're also called the [Analytic Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set)
[image]

and the second one is (see P. 268):
[image]

I understand that:

**Definition (Souslin set):** A Souslin set is a continuous image of a complete, separable (= having a countable dense subset) metric space that's also Hausdorff (see. P. 19 in the same book)
[image]

Now given the definition, I think it's clear that **[Borel sigma algebra is strictly contained in the signma algebra generated by analytic/Souslin sets](https://projects.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/topology/?page_id=2185), but not vice versa**. But **then I wonder why, on P.268 of the book above, the author writes: "Theorem 9.1.3 is an immediate corollary of Theorem 6.9.1"? It's clear that a selection or choice or right inverse of $F$ is measurable w.r.t. to the sigma algebra of analytic sets, so inverse images by $F$ are analytic, but why must they be Borel?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting function will, in general, not be Borel measurable, and Bogachev doesn't write that it is. Theorem 9.1.3. is about the completion (!) of (finite) Borel measures on $Y$. That is, if you have a measure defined on all Borel sets and look at the $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ generated by all Borel sets and subsets of Borel sets of measure zero, then $g$ is measurable with respect to the resulting $\sigma$-algebra. That this works follows from Theorem 7.4.1.

Comment: Thank you, may I ask this follow up question?

In "$g$ is measurable w.r.t. *every* Borel measure on $Y$": the term "with respect to a Borel measure" confuses me: to define measurability of a map, we just need that the pre-images of measurable sets are measurable and we don't need a measure to define measurability of a map. But I looked at your answer: "That is...$g$ is measurable... resulting $\sigma$ algebra." Here, you added extra $\mu$-null sets to the Borel $\sigma$ -algebra to define measurability - is it the explanation of "$g$ is measurable w.r.t. *every* Borel measure $\mu$ on $Y$"?

Comment: And if yes, could you please cite a source for this? Apologies if this is a very rudimentary question, but I've forgotten some parts of my measure theory from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Also, another question: in here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.13347.pdf, see: "Jankoff’s Theorem 2.12", it seems wrong then, as the author assumed that the map right inverse map $g:Y\to X$ is Borel measurable, instead of what you explained. Am I correct?

Comment: Bogachev defines the completion slightly differently, see Definition 1.5.10. For nonnegative finite measures, this is equivalent to what I wrote above. The reference you mention seems to be indeed incorrect.